# How to display upvoted posts by user in a view?

Tags: views, rating

I want to display nodes upvoted by user in userprofile page in a view. I have number up/down rate widget with nodes, and user can take back votes by clicking on vote arrows.

I tried this:

**Relationship**:

- node:votes
- node: vote results

**Contexual Filters**

- votes:user = -node-votes(user)

**Filter criteria**

- (Vote results) Vote results: Value (> 0)

**Problem**

first problem is, whenever a user take an upvote back, and upvote again on same node, it duplicates on view result.

second problem = absolute value of vote result in field criteria is greater than 0. and this also brings downvoted posts on this view.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Hi Please check the data filters and widget type, for more details read readme file of module, there is (Views integration section)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Its working great if you configure according to documentation. 
Thanks!

Comment: thanks. i did like in the first image at it worked. but what is the second image for?

Comment: Its for view Filed in expanded form (Voting result ) you can select widget as per requirement. I have added more image in answer for convenience.